# Access - Search computer for field with button

Tags: windows, ms-access, search

In an access form, I'm trying to make a button that essentially does the same as hitting "Windows+F" -> opens a folder and searches for the text from a selected field in the form.

If I can figure this out (with your help) it will save hundreds of clicks and key presses a day.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks
Brad

Comment: Brad, glad you are here. You may want to edit your question a bit to remove the "fluff". One key I like to remember is "Ask your question as if you are asking a very very busy colleague."

Answer (score 0):

You can try SendKeys: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278655.aspx

or if you want to work with the results, several examples from here:
http://software-solutions-online.com/2014/03/05/list-files-and-folders-in-a-directory/

Comment: Thanks M.Castro,
Not quite what I had in mind, but seems the closest option. Thank you